# Jooq too many clients

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jooq

I'm facing an "Too many clients" error when using jooq in my spring boot application.
Currently I'm autowiring my DSLContext and was hoping that jooq auto closes the connections to my postgres, which apparently does not work properly.
Is there a way of releasing the connection manually?

```
  @Autowired
  lateinit var dsl: DSLContext


  //further down
  dsl.close() //didn't help
```

I found ideas which suggest to do something like this (Java code but you get the point ;) ),
but i would like to stick with the idea of autowiring the DSLContext (like above) and not the DataSource itself:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
//Further down 
Connection con=dataSource.getConnection();
DSLContext create = DSL.using(con, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
//Execute code here
con.close();
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the proper transaction manager and that you properly marked the transactional methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably control flows that lead to your `con.close()` call being skipped. However, you don't have to do the connection management manually with jOOQ. Just pass the `DataSource` to your `DSL.using()` call instead:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

//Further down 
DSLContext create = DSL.using(dataSource, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
```